# Oracle SQL select records where percentage of one column is above a certain amount

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns of data and I need to select only the rows where the percentage is above a certain percentage of another (say 80%). So in the table below the only records selected would be rows 2 and 4 in the table pic. I also need to avoid any rows where either value is = 0.

[image: Table]

I have tried using ratio_to_report but just can't seem to make it work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage is a ratio of two values per 100. So the formula would be percentage=**Hours**/**Est Hours** x 100. Conversely 80% would be a ratio of 0.8. So your *where* condition could be Hours/"Est Hours">0.8.  Please note that since your column name has a space it has to be enclosed in double quotes.

```
select * from table where Hours/"Est Hours">0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from job_hours where Hours/"Est Hours">0.8 and "Est Hours"<>0